# PHP: How to save a file in a directory that does not exist?

Tags: php

How can I save a file in a directory that does not exist?

In other words, it would have to automatically create the directory/sub-directories (if it does not exist) and then save the file to it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everyone provided an answer, but forgot to turn the recursive flag on. You must specify mkdir's third argument to true, to create directory tree ([from mkdir manual](http://php.net/mkdir)):

```
<?php
// Desired folder structure
$structure = './depth1/depth2/depth3/';

// To create the nested structure, the $recursive parameter 
// to mkdir() must be specified.

if (!mkdir($structure, 0, true)) {
    die('Failed to create folders...');
}

// ...
?>
```

Comment: OK, so there's no way to do it automatically, you must always do a manual check and create it if it does not exist?

Comment: The check that is performed here is checking whether directory was sucessfully created (returns true). If your webserver doesn't have permissions to do this task, it will return false. It's just an error checking. Sure, before creating directory, take suggestions from others to check with is_dir if it exists. You should realize that computer is dumb and you have to tell him what to do in each ad every case (if possible) or else he will cry..ash.

Answer (score 4):

[Create the directory](http://php.net/mkdir) first.

Comment: OK, so there's no way to do it automatically, you must always do a manual check and create it if it does not exist?

Comment: Right, although you might consider always doing mkdir and just letting it fail if the directory already exists.

Comment: @Juhana:  That's an interesting approach.  Are there any Cons to doing that?

Comment: @Programmer I added it as a new answer. The possible con is that you don't know if mkdir failed because the directory couln't be created or if it already exists.

Answer (score 4):

```
    if(!is_dir ( "foldername" ))
    {
    mkdir("foldername");
    }
```

Comment: OK, so there's no way to do it automatically, you must always do a manual check and create it if it does not exist?

Comment: before you save the file to the location , you make a check whether the pointed directory exists or not..

Comment: What about Juhana's solution above "Right, although you might consider always doing mkdir and just letting it fail if the directory already exists. " ?  Is that advisable?

Comment: mk dir will be executed only if the folder is not there..    if(!is_dir ( "foldername" ))

Comment: I understand that, but can't you safe on having to check using if(!is_dir (...)) and just use mkdir which will automatically check and fail if the dir already exists ?  Would there be a problem with that one-line solution?

Answer (score 2):

```
if(!is_dir($dir)){
mkdir($dir);
}
```

Comment: OK, so there's no way to do it automatically, you must always do a manual check and create it if it does not exist?

Answer (score 2):

You could skip the is_dir check and try mkdir every time. mkdir just fails if the directory already exists. Theoretically you have to check that the mkdir succeeded anyway:

```
mkdir( $dir, 0777, true );

if( !is_writable( $dir ) ) {
    die( "$dir is not writable" );
}
```